# resize mounted partition with gparted

Tags: partition, hard-disk, gparted

I have the following partitions on my machine:

[image]

I want to resize `/dev/sda5` and stick it to `sda4`, but `gparted` doesn't allow me.

How can I do it?

Comment: resize it *how*? and what does "stick it to sda4" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, you need to unmount it first. And because it is your `/` filesystem, you need to use a LiveCD (GParted has a special LiveCD but you can use the Ubuntu installation image too).

Some filesystems can be resized when mounted and ext4 is one of them, but you don't want to just resize it, you also need to move the entire partition to the left, because partitions can be resized only to the right. This means copying the data and it cannot be done when the partition is mounted.

Note that the *Resize/Move* operation in GParted can be dangerous (for example losing power during it would be really bad) so make sure to backup your data first.